# Using DBI::CSV module of Perl. Get undef for empty string while parsing the csv

Tags: perl, csv, perl-module, dbi

I'm using DBI::CSV module in Perl to parse my csv and run queries on the data.

My data is something like this

```
1001|23|1|loading  
1012|25||loading
```

I want the 3rd field in the second row to be undef, which I'm not able to achieve. I'm getting the field as an empty string instead of undef with this is the piece of code I tried.

```
use strict;  
use warnings "all";  
use Text::CSV_XS;  
use DBI;  
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, {  
                            csv_sep_char    => "|",  
                            f_dir           => ".",  
                            csv_eol         => "\n",  
                            csv_empty_is_undef  => 1,  
                            csv_blank_is_undef  => 1,  
                            csv_quote_char  => undef,  
                            csv_escape_char => undef,  
                            csv_always_quote => undef,  
                            f_ext           => ".csv",  
                            f_enc           => "utf-8",  
                            csv_class       => "Text::CSV_XS",  
                            RaiseError      => 1,  
                            PrintError      => 1  
                            }  
                       );
my @cols = ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4");
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}{'info'} = { 'file' => "file.csv", col_names => \@cols };
my $result =$dbh->selectall_hashref( "select col1,col2,col3,col4 from info where col1 = 1012", "col1")  

#gives the following result
0  HASH(0x992573c)  
   1012 => HASH(0x9900e90)
  'col1' => 1012
  'col2' => '25'
  'col3' => ''
  'col4' => 'loading'
```

I'm expecting the value of col3 as undef here.
Any help here would me appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You declare @cols as an array, but then you assign an array reference to it, i.e. you only initialize its first element. Do not use square brackets for arrays, only for array references:

```
my @cols = ( "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}{'info'} = { 'file' => "file.csv", col_names => \@cols };
```

With:

```
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}{'info'} = { 'file' => "file.csv", col_names => @cols };
```

Results in:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1012' => {
                      'col3' => undef,
                      'col1' => '1012',
                      'col2' => '25',
                      'col4' => 'loading'
                    }
        };
```

Comment: I have added your suggestion but I still get same result as empty string.

Comment: I ran your code, and your sample, and got exactly what you requested as desired output, so I don't know what is wrong with your code, is your above code exactly the same as what you are running?

Comment: Yes it is exactly same.

Comment: Do you see my `$result` dump? it is using your code with my minor fix

Comment: Yes, But not sure why I am not getting the expected result

Comment: I noticed that I also commented `#csv_class       => "Text::CSV_XS"` because my environment didn't have it, maybe that is the reason?